# Clang generates local store in LLVM IR

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-ir

I'm learning LLVM IR through Clang and found out that a C function like:

```
int inc(int x)
{
  return x+1;
}
```

Generates this IR (optimizations are turned off):

```
define i32 @inc(i32 %x) #0 {
entry:
  %x.addr = alloca i32, align 4
  store i32 %x, i32* %x.addr, align 4
  %0 = load i32, i32* %x.addr, align 4
  %add = add nsw i32 %0, 1
  ret i32 %add
}
```

My question is to know exactly why it allocates in the first place a local (x.addr) store, then load from it.

Comment: Never mind, `mem2reg` pass will take care of all the redundant allocas.

Comment: @SK-logic: it's mostly SROA these days :)

Comment: @EliBendersky: why do you mean by "it's mostly Scalar Replacement Of Aggregates" ?

Comment: @Stringer: I mean in the optimization pipeline today SROA does this transformation (allocas to SSA values)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because this is unoptimized code. Clang (the frontend) doesn't spend much (almost any?) time figuring out how to make the code it emits optimal. It leaves it to the backend optimizations (LLVM). Local variables are "on the stack" in unoptimized mode, which means the `alloca`. It also means that `x` has an addressable location, which may or may not be used later. Without optimizations the compiler does not know whether it's going to be used, so it conservatively generates an addresable location anyway.

```
int inc(int x)
{
  x = x + 1;
  int* px = &x;
  return x;
}
```

Now Clang emits:

```
define i32 @inc(i32 %x) #0 {
entry:
  %x.addr = alloca i32, align 4
  %px = alloca i32*, align 8
  store i32 %x, i32* %x.addr, align 4
  %0 = load i32, i32* %x.addr, align 4
  %add = add nsw i32 %0, 1
  store i32 %add, i32* %x.addr, align 4
  store i32* %x.addr, i32** %px, align 8
  %1 = load i32, i32* %x.addr, align 4
  ret i32 %1
}
```

See the address `%x.addr` being used for the pointer now?

Of course if you run this through the optimizer you get:

```
define i32 @inc(i32 %x) #0 {
entry:
  %add = add nsw i32 %x, 1
  ret i32 %add
}
```

Which is probably more in line with what you'd expect from a compiler.

Comment: Thank you. I see, but still something is puzzling me with how Clang works related to stack alloc. I had the feeling it does so because in C, any stack variable can be touched via a side effect. So it has to load from memory "just in case". I've tried to compile this: `int test(int x, int y)
{
  *((&y)+1) = 7;
  return x+1;
}` but the odd thing is that with optims turned on, still generates the same code that in my question, albeit `x` gets clobbered.

Comment: @Stringer: with optimizations on, the code you posted compiles to my latest IR sample in the answer (with an extra argument `%y` which is unused)